# Making Twitter Bootstrap Modal window bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modal to show images.

How do I simply make `Twitter Bootstrap` modal window bigger?

I'm using code from the ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200404/twitter-bootstrap-modal-width-issues)) question:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        show: false
    }).css({
        // make width 90% of screen
       'width': function () { 
           return ($(document).width() * .9) + 'px';  
       },
        // center model
       'margin-left': function () { 
           return -($(this).width() / 2); 
       }
});
```

But here's the result:

[image]

I have to scroll it down. How do I keep image ratio and show it without a scrollbar?

Comment: Completely irrelevant, but I do not like camelcased css selectors. But that is just a matter of taste :)

Comment: Me too. I like splitting them by a dash. I've just copied it from source and that's all:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we show images with bootstrap modal, we use the following css:

```
#myModal {
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;

  .modal-body {
    max-height: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

And then just do

```
$('#myModal').modal("show");
```

The crux is setting the `max-height` on `.modal-body` to `none`.

Comment: Sorry, that is true: I use sass in most of my projects (rails developer here).